# 32-х и 64-х битные COM объекты

Tags: c, com, c++

Как проверить, каким является COM объект: 32-х или 64-х битным?

Comment: вам требуется программный способ проверки?

Comment: @IAZ по-моему, теги вопроса вполне недвусмысленно намекают… Хотя, возможно, это как раз тот случай, когда автор перестарался с тегами…

Comment: А что, есть аппаратный? :) Имеется в виду, что необходимо понять является ли библиотека 32х битной или она 64х битная.

Comment: программный - это значит написать программу, которой определяет какого типа заданный COM компонент. но уже понятно что вам это не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может это и не лучший способ, но работает. Для проверки необходимо скопировать COM объект на 32-х битную машину и попробовать его зарегистрировать. Если COM объект 32-х битный, он зарегистрируется, если 64-х битный, то появится сообщение о том, что ОС и COM объект несовместимы. Замечу, что обратное не верно, т.е. если попробовать зарегистрировать 32-х битный компонент на 64-х битной системе, то он зарегистрируется.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попытаться найти dll, соответствующиую этому объекту и проанализировать PE-заголовок на предмет разрядности (см. PE32+).